# Where do i specify the "fields" parameter using the Google API Client Library - PHP (Beta)

Tags: google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Google API Client Library - PHP (Beta) for youtube data api v3
I'm doing a playlist list operation according to the docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
 however i can't find a way of providing the fields parameter using the API Client Library.

Is there anyone who got an idea to would i go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`fields` is a standard query parameter ([as defined here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/standard_parameters)).

It should be supported by the Youtube API and you may pass it in the `$params` array parameter, along with `$maxResults`, etc. Please refer to the sample you provided to see where is `$params`.

Answer (score 1):

define in **$queryParams**

```
...

// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);


$queryParams = [
  'maxResults' => 3,
  'type' => 'video',
  'q' => 'car',
  'fields' => 'items(snippet(title))'
];

$response = $service->search->listSearch('snippet', $queryParams);
...
```